# How to get Gmail API error code by Struct field name?

Tags: go

The Gmail API err response struct includes a Code field according to [Examiner](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/learning-to-use-go-reflection-822a0aed74b7)

```
_, err := gmailService.Users.Messages.Send("me", &gMsg).Do()
t := reflect.TypeOf(err)
examiner(t,0)
```

Response

```
Type is  and kind is ptr
 Contained type:
 Type is Error and kind is struct
     Field 1 name is Code type is int and kind is int
...
```

I can successfully get the error code using the field index, but that is more obscure (and therefore more difficult to maintain) and feels more fragile:

```
errReflectElem := reflect.ValueOf(err).Elem() 
fmt.Printf("err.Code %v\n",errReflectElem.Field(0).Interface())
```

It appears that I should also be able to get the error code as follows based on [this sample](https://play.golang.org/p/sXnpj_dV8pa):

```
fmt.Println("Code: %v",err.Code)
```

However that gives a build error:

```
err.Code undefined (type error has no field or method Code)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1#UsersMessagesSendCall.Do) it returns a `*googleapi.Error`. Simply assert to this type and you have full access to everything it contains. This is a prime example of the power of interfaces and proper error handling via an exported type. If such an error type is exported, there is no reflection necessary to access it.

```
if gapiErr, ok := err.(*googleapi.Error); ok {
    // use gapiErr.WhateverField
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the doc link is what I'd been missing somehow... earlier I'd been trying to assert to *Error instead of *googleapi.Error.  Interestingly, the googleapi package isn't installed by default with the rest of the api packages, so that's an explicit get.

Comment: @user1318390 Yeah, looks like it's a standardized error across many of their API packages. Keep in mind that package boundaries are strictly enforced by the language.